# How to implement the effect of Prezi presentation?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, powerpoint, slice, prezi

"mindmap" in Prezi presentation is cool. 
But how to implement it in OpenCV?
Or has any JS library provided the similar API to achieve it?
Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried? show us the "cool" code..

Comment: visual presentation effects aren't computer vision but computer graphics. Probably there exist better libraries than opencv for that task.